# get the return value of a function when calling to it with subprocess

Tags: python

I have a function that return a string.

I want to call it using subprocess.

The function also prints debug messages using print.

How do I get the function return string (i can't read stdout since i have debug messages there also)

Comment: Where is the function that you think you need `subprocess` to call it?

Comment: Send the debug messages to a log file instead of stdout.

Comment: Can you not use the `multiprocessing` module instead to call the function more directly? Anyway, if you have to use `subprocess` and `print` to stdout, then write your result to stderr or a file.